# Windows Forms SingletoneFormProvider and using second constructor to get some parameters

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `MDI Forms` application and I use `SingletoneFormProvider` because it's required to have only one instance of a form in a time.

I have Edit forms that can be used for creating new records or changing existing ones. The problem is with the editing of an existing record.

What I've done so far :

- I have a method that calls the static method from the `SingletoneProviderForm` class and get fresh instance of the form :

  ```
      protected void LoadForm<T>(ToolStripItem formButton, string buttonText, long? loadEntityId = null, bool closeAlreadyOpened = true) where T : BaseForm
  {
           //Some code..
           openForm = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance<T>(parentFrm, closeAlreadyOpened);
           openForm.LoadEntityId = loadEntityId;
           openForm.MdiParent = parentFrm;
           openForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           openForm.Show();
           openForm.Activate();
           //More code..
  ```

  }
- I have three delcarations of the `SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance<T>` :

  static public T GetInstance(Form owner)
              where T : Form

  static public T GetInstance(Form owner, bool closeAllButThis)
              where T : BaseForm

  static public T GetInstance(Form owner, bool closeAllButThis, params object[] args)
      where T : Form
- Till now to get a fresh instance of any form I did this :

  LoadForm();
- If I want to send an Id then just :

  LoadForm(ID);

And here comes the problem. Because I try to populate the Form fields with data from the record with the provided ID I make a query :

```
entity = anyForm.Find(LoadEntityId.Value);
```

And all this actually worked fine while I was doing it in the `form_load` event. But now when I move this part in the constructor everytime I do the check :

```
if (LoadEntityId.HasValue)
```

It never has because it seems that the way the form instance is constructed I don't have access to the ID from the constructor.

What I did :

- Made a change in the `LoadForm()` method:

  if (loadEntityId == null)
                  {
                      openForm = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance(parentFrm, closeAlreadyOpened);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     openForm = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance(parentFrm, closeAlreadyOpened, loadEntityId);
                  }
- Made my default constructor protected and remove everything from it :

  protected AnyForm()
  {}
- Made another constructor that takes one argument:

  public AnyForm(long? LoadEntityId)
  {
      long? AnyFormID = LoadEntityId.Value;
      InitializeComponent();
      //All the stuff that I needed
  }

So it was amazing for me that it works. I have big doubts that this is the way to accomplish this. So please review and guide me to the correct way of doing this. And of course, if this is somehow the correct way please verify because I'm in doubt if it's ok to put this in production code.

P.S

As `Matthew Watson`  mentioned the form behave weird without default constructor so I end up with one default (no argument) constructor and another one taking one argument - the ID I need. Which makes it even worse, now I have duplicated code. I'm pretty sure that's not how it's done.

Comment: What happens now if you look at that form in the form designer? Does it work OK? (The designer wants a default constructor, so it may do something weird without it, or just fail outright.)

Comment: Yeah I do have a problem. When I try to call `LoadForm<AnyForm>()` with this code I get `Missing method exception . Constructor on type.. not found".